# I Create application with Parse and i have to edit saved content

Tags: ios, parse-platform

i Create a app with parse backend and i save the details like name,username,password,gender so the problem i face to update that details which saved on parse

how to update that detail?

Answer (score 2):

You need to read out the Parse.com documentation [iOS Developers Guide](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide)

Let's say you want to save the `User` to the Parse Cloud. The interface is similar to a `NSMutableDictionary`, plus the `saveInBackground` method:

```
PFObject *user= [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"User"];
user[@"id"] = @1337;
user[@"name"] = @"Sean Plott";
user[@"password"] = @"abc123";
[user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
  if (succeeded) {
    // The object has been saved.
  } else {
    // There was a problem, check error.description
  }
}];
```

Comment: no i do that but no work

Comment: i want to update the field like i save the name on parse ok now i define edit button and one textbox that text change the name on parse database name

Comment: I am not getting that what issue you are facing.